# Proof that a module homomorphism between group algebras over a field has an eigenvalue

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $G$ be a finite group, $k$ an algebraically closed field and $kG$ the group algebra of $G$ over $k$. Let $M$ be a module over $kG$. Let $V$ be an irreducible/simple $kG$-modules.

In the proofs of one version of schur's lemma (for example, on Page 8 of [this](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph251/schur.pdf)), it is often used that if $\phi: V \to V$ is a $kG$-homomorphism, then since the base field of $V$ is algebraically closed, as a linear mapping on $V, \phi$ has an eigenvalue $a \in k$.

I haven't seen a proof of this, and I was wondering how to prove it.

I looked at the wikipaedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field), and the proof for a normal linear map from $k^n$ to $k^n$ uses the fact that endomorphisms from vector spaces of finite dimension can be represented by a matrix on any basis and then you can use the characteristic polynomial.

I am trying to make a similar argument using the more abstract analogues of all these things. Obviously, the module homomorphism is the analogue of a linear map. Do I then show that $kG$ modules are finite dimension vector spaces over $k$, and hence $\phi$ could be represented by some matrix with values in $k$, so it's characteristic polynomial has a root?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you must use somewhere that $\dim(V)>0$, which to be sure is ensured by the definition of a simple $kG$ module. Even over an algebraically closed field, not _every_ monic polynomial has a root.

Comment: Also, your title is misleading, since you are not talking about ring homomorphisms, but about module homomorphisms.

Comment: you're right thanks, just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do I then show that  modules are finite dimension vector spaces over , and hence  could be represented by some matrix with values in , so it's characteristic polynomial has a root?"

Yes. This is the completely standard approach. Strictly speaking you could use an abstract definition of the determinant to define the characteristic polynomial abstractly and avoid coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if this is a dumb question but why are $kG$-modules finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$? What would the basis be explicitly? From other problems it looks like you can pick an $m \in M-0$, and then if $G = \{g_1, ..., g_n\}$, $\{g_1m, ..., g_nm\}$ is a basis. Why is that a basis though? I don't see why for an arbitrary $m' \in M, m' = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ig_im$ for $\lambda_i \in k$.

Comment: They are not in general. I assumed you simply omitted the word and intended finiteness to be a background hypothesis. In your case, $V$ is irreducible, and irreducible $kG$-modules are finite-dimensional. One way to see that is that $\{g_1 m, \ldots, g_n m\}$ spans a non-trivial $kG$-submodule of a $kG$-module $M$ when $m \in M - \{0\}$. Note that this latter set is *not* a basis in general, e.g. take $M$ to be the one-dimensional trivial representation where $g \cdot m = m$ for all $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you choose to, avoid the characteristic polynomial and use the minimal polynomial instead; the advantage is that minimal polynomials can easily (and should) be defined without ever using a basis.

First of all, a simple $kG$ module is of nonzero dimension by definition. Also (to repeat what was said in a comment to another answer) finite dimensionality of the module$~V$ as a vector space follows from the fact that, given any nonzero $v$ in the module, $kG\cdot v$ is a finite dimensional (since $kG$ is) nonzero sub-module of$~V$, and therefore by irreducibility equal to$~V$.

Now for any linear operator $\phi:V \to V$ (whether a $kG$ module morphism or not), the powers $\phi^0=I_V$, $\phi^1=\phi$, $\phi^2$, $\phi^3,\ldots$, forming an infinite  sequence of $k$-endomorphisms of$~V$, must be linearly dependent, since the space of such $k$-endomorphisms is finite dimensional (its dimension is $\dim_k(V)^2$). If the first linear dependence involves $\phi^0,\ldots,\phi^d$, then it can be taken to have a coefficient $1$ for $\phi^d$, and thus give a monic polynomial$~P$ of degree$~d$ that annihilates$~\phi$. We have $d\neq0$ since $\dim(V)\neq0$ (so $I_V\neq0$), so that by algebraic closure of $k$, there is some root $\alpha\in k$ of$~P$. Wrinting $P=(X-\alpha)Q$ in $k[X]$, one has $Q[T]\neq0$ (by the minimality of $P$), but $0=P[\phi]=(\phi-\alpha I_v)\circ Q[\phi]$ shows that every vector in the image of $Q[\phi]$ is in $\ker(\phi-\alpha I_v)$, the eigenspace for$~\alpha$ of $\phi$. This shows that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$, which is what was to be proved.